# Writing binary in C

Tags: c, file, binary

I am trying to write the value 0000 0100 (which is 4 in decimal) into a binary file in C. Here is my code:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("D:\\test.COM", "wb");
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("error creating file");
    return -1;
}
int val = 100;  // value 4
fwrite(&val, sizeof val, 1, fp);
fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

Can someone correct me? I don't want to assign 4 to val, I want to write actual binary in the code.

Thanks,

Comment: What you have up there is a byte but you are writing an int (4 bytes, usually).

Comment: Thanks, how do I write just one byte? and I want to write actual bin. So, 00000100 and if I look at the output in a hex editor, it should hold 0x4.

Comment: @user3282081, You can just use a `char` type, which is an `8-bit` type in C.

Comment: do you mean like: char *val = 00000100; // I am not sure how that will work?

Comment: @user3282081, See the update where I explain how to convert a binary string into a binary-valued `char`, for feeding into `fwrite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the file to actually have the bits `0000 0010`, then you want an 8-bit int, which is a `char` in C.

```
char val = (char) 4;  // value 4
fwrite(&val, sizeof val, 1, fp);
```

Update: Based on the comments, it looks like the OP is asking how to convert a binary **string** of the form "00000010" into the bit representation. Yes, there is a way, but it requires you to do bit masking. The following should get you started.

```
char* input = "00000010";
char output = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    if (input[i] == '1')
       output |= (1 << (7-i)); // Set the appropriate sit of `output` to 1.
```

You can then use `fwrite` as in the first part of my answer.

Since BLUEPIXY did not write his own answer, I am incorporating his comment into this answer for completeness. While I think the above loop is instructive for a beginner, it is much faster to use the library function that he mentioned.

```
char val=strtol("00000100", NULL, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I don't want to write 4, I want to write binary. I am using different types of calculations to figure out every bit and then I will construct the binary value for example: 10110100 and then I want to write that binary into the binary file.

Comment: @user3282081, When you use `fwrite`, and you open your file in a hex editor, you will see the bits you want. The function `fwrite` will write the *value* 4, which in binary is `00000010`. This is very different from if you use a function like `fprintf`, which would print the ASCII representation of the character `4`.

Comment: I understand that part. However, at the time of writing it, I don't know the hex equivalent of it, I only have the value in binary.

Comment: @user3282081, By binary, do you mean like a binary string? If so, how are you generating the binary string?

Comment: @user3282081, When you say "I only have the value in binary", what exactly does it look like?

Comment: Yes, the binary string. I have a set of conditions to figure out the bits, 0s and 1s. Now, after running that piece of code, I will end up with a binary string of, let's say "00000100" or anything else in binary. To write this IN BINARY, is there a way in C?

Comment: Thanks Merlin, I tried your code, but the output was: 0001000 in binary. My binary string was 4 "00000100". The output written in file was 0001000 which is 10. Any idea?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY your solution worked as well. but it writes 4 bytes, not 1 byte. I guess that is because int is 4 bytes?

Comment: @user3282081 `char val=strtol("00000100", NULL, 2);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - thank you so much, your solution is much simpler and works very well. So, I did  char val = strtol("00000100", NULL, 2);

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to specify it in binary?

int val = 0b100;  // value 4

Comment: I have a set of conditions in the code that can generate the binary string. So, it figures out what each bit is gonna be, so after executing that part, I will end up with, say "00000100" or anything else. Now I want to find a way to write this binary value AS BINARY in the output file.